# How to know if a downloadable file exists on my computer?

Tags: 14.04

I don't want to download a file twice. So,I want to get a notification (with the destination of containing folder), when I will attempt to download a file which exists in my computer.Is it possible?I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: What are you using to download?

Comment: If you try to download a file into a folder where another of the same name exists, you will be asked if you want to overwrite it.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Most browsers I've used just download another copy and call it `whatever(1)`.

Comment: On my Ubuntu it will happily ad (n) to the file-name, ex: document.pdf, document(1).pdf, document(2).pdf...  which is fine, when it is different pdf's -  And teher will be No warning! - then I have to rename them to something appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command to locate files in your computer.

But if you need something to index and notify, you must look at softwares like **Basenji**, **Tracker**, **Beagle**, **Recoll**.These are indexing softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that such a "solution" might have side-effects / flip-side.

If your solution acts just on filenames - you might be limited if you try to download another 'image.jpg' while there exists already a file by that name (different image itself) in that specific target folder.

So a better approach would be combining filename with additional informations (as example: some kind of checksum), which again will most likely slow-down the comparison process

I doubt there is a good solution without flipside for your situation

Just wanted to show the major flipside ... that filename is often not enough to know if a file already exists at a specific location or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can search it on your dash or, even if you try to download the same file which exists on your computer , computer will ask whether to replace or create new file